# Plotting and manipulate with min/max inside and free parameters

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I shall reformulate my question with a better attempt.

My goal is to plot a (alleged) function `ee[..]` which depends on another function `f` stationary points and derivatives which itself depend on two other parameters `betta` and `h`. I would like to plot `ee[h_,..]` and eventually stick the `Plot[ee[h_,..]` into a `Manipulate[...,{betta,1,2}`. For now, `betta = 1.264`.

```
(* Source of dependency on h *)
betta = 1.264;
f[x_, b_, h_] := -0.5*x^2 - 
   h*x + (1/b)*0.5*((1 + x)*Log[1 + x] + (1 - x)*Log[1 - x]);

(* Function to be plotted*)
ee[fmstar_, fmbar_, mstar_, mbar_, fmb_, fms_, b_, h_] := 
  Exp[fmbar - fmstar]*Sqrt[(1 - mstar)/(1 - mbar)]*
   Pi/(2*b*Sqrt[-fms*fmb]);

(* Define max, min and second derivative of f as func. of h, I know how f behaves and so I expect it to have one local max near zero and 2 mins on the left and on the right. I pick the left one. *)
fmax[h_] := FindMaximum[{f[x, betta, h], -1 < x < 1}, {x, 0}];
fmin[h_] := FindMinimum[{f[x, betta, h], -1 < x < 1}, {x, -0.05}]
fxx[h_] := D[f[x, betta, h], {x, 2}];

(* Try to supply the various parameter and plot *)
  (Plot[{
   ee[
    (fmax[h])[[1]],
    (fmin[h])[[1]],
    mstar = x /. (fmax[h])[[2]],
    mbar = x /. (fmin[h])[[2]],
    fxx[h] /. x -> mbar,
    fxx[h] /. x -> mstar,
    betta, h]
   },
  {h, 0.005, -0.005},
  ImageSize -> 500
  ]
 )
```

but I get an empty plot here.

If you need to inspect `f` this manipulate is convenient.

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, b, h], {x, -1, 1}, GridLines -> {{-0.5, 0.5}}, ImageSize -> 500], {b, 0.2, 2}, {h, -1, 1}]
```

For my purposes

$ -1<x<1, b >1$ and $h\in(\pm \frac{1}{2b}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{b}})$

Comment: I am still not quite sure what you trie to achive, but you should have a look at the output structure of `FindMinimum`. Also you have some problems with complex values which cannot be plotted.

Comment: I know I have some points where this should not work, but it is ok for me to work in a subset of the parameter where all minima and maxima are well defined.

What I want is just plotting the ee[] function as a function of h. Only, ee depends on h in a funny way through the position of minima and maxima of the f function.

Comment: @meneken17 I have reformulated the question, hopefully is clearer now.

Comment: Much clearer now.
There are 2 mistakes: 
1) in the definition of `ee` you use `fmb` did you mean 'fmm'?
2) `fxx` only has 1 argumetn, but you call it with 3 in the plot command.

Comment: Right I was fixing those, but I am not sure, should I just declare it w/ three arguments fxx?

Comment: Ah. And a 3rd Mistake: you misplaced the `]` use `fxx[h_] := D[f[x, betta, h], {x, 2}];` instead.
Then you get an expression wich only contains `x` as variable.
I would then use `/.x-> "yor value"` to evaluate.

Comment: Ah, now it works! Thanks for your useful points!